# I'm unable to connect to mysql from nodejs.I get the following error

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Handshake.js:130:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/gayathri/jsonhbs/db1.js:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
```

Comment: did you try to access the mysql server using mysql client (linux command) with same username and password? Seems like an authorization error

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you're not even passing a user ? This is indeed a authentication error.

Comment: I'm able to access through linux command and yes,I have passed a user.That's why I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error message, you can clearly see that you did not send the correct user field with the mysql connection call.

Ensure that you send the user you would like to connect as.

Which mysql library are you using? In felix-node-mysql, you must pass the following object:

`mysql.createConnection({host:"localhost",user:"root",password:"secretpasshere"},function(...){...})`

Comment: Thank you.I got it